# NEST thermostat hot water status and control missing from API

Tags: nest, nest-device-access

I would like to control Nest thermostat (3rd gen with heatlink) domestic hot water, however the API doesn't seem to be exposing neither it's controls nor it's status (https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/thermostat). As there's clearly at least an internal API for that, which the thermostat itself is using: would it be possible to expose the same controls/stat for external use?
Use-cases:

- home assistant integration
- triggering a 'boost' with a push button

Update 2022-11-07:
There's a homeassistant integration called 'badnest', which is using an unofficial local API. I've noticed, that on that API for hot water readings and controls are exposed and as such made a contribution to the integration so that it would also be exposed in HA: https://github.com/badguy99/badnest/pull/11

Comment: Moved to a house with a Nest smart thermostat. Turns out Google's API is so limited I'd probably qualify this as a dumb thermostat... and they even charge $5 for API access!  I hope they can implement this in the public API since it's available through the app.

Comment: Added a bounty to this question.. Just wondered if you managed to get anwhere with this?

Comment: I actually have. I've updated the original question with the details.

Comment: Is the badnest integration compatible with the standard Nest integration in Home Assistant? I have a doorbell as well as a thermostat and wouldn't want to lose the standard integration.

Answer (score 0):

This [Google help page](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9259109?visit_id=637995077643095972-934393175&hl=en-GB&rd=1#zippy=%2Chow-will-i-know-if-my-heating-system-is-opentherm-compatible) suggests that the Nest Thermostat is using [OpenTherm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenTherm) commands to control the water boiler. If so, then your water boiler must have an OpenTherm interface. You could use some other hardware to interface with your water boiler, for example [this DIY OpenTherm gateway](http://otgw.tclcode.com), which will allow you to control the boiler programmatically with OpenTherm commands. This would allow home assistant integration, or a DIY push-button for boost.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the worst aspects of Best, being able to bost hot water is essential, since it is in the app when is it not available though API.  I realise this is probably because having separate water tanks that are controlled independently is not as common in the states and Nest us very USA centric, but the feature is key in the app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).